# Discord.py app_commands.required command tree no attribute

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
        @client.tree.command(name='decide', description='Bing will now help you to decide what happens')        
        @app_commands.describe(choice1 = "What is your 1st choice?")
        @app_commands.describe(choice2 = "What is your 2nd choice?")
        @app_commands.describe(choice3 = "What is your 3rd choice?")
        @app_commands.required(choice3 = False)
        @app_commands.describe(choice4 = "What is your 4th choice?")
        @app_commands.requiredt(choice3 = False)
        @app_commands.describe(choice5 = "What is your 5th choice?")
        @app_commands.required(choice3 = False)
        async def decide(interaction: discord.Interaction, choice1: str, choice2: str, choice3: str, choice4: str, choice5: str):
            print(choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4, choice5)
```

Discord.py documentation claims for there to be a "required" @app_commands attribute for checking if the input is required, returns an error saying it is not there

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\relen\Downloads\BingChatAI.py", line 987, in <module>
    @app_commands.required(choice3 = False)
AttributeError: module 'discord.app_commands' has no attribute 'required'
```

Comment: maybe you read old documentation, or you use old `discord.py`, or you use different module for discord.

Comment: you could add link to documentation because I don't see `required` in documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want those to be optional you have two ways for that

First:

```
import typing
@bot.tree.command(name='decide', description='Bing will now help you to decide what happens')        
@app_commands.describe(choice1 = "What is your 1st choice?")
@app_commands.describe(choice2 = "What is your 2nd choice?")
@app_commands.describe(choice3 = "What is your 3rd choice?")
@app_commands.describe(choice4 = "What is your 4th choice?")
@app_commands.describe(choice5 = "What is your 5th choice?")
async def decide(interaction: discord.Interaction, choice1: str, choice2: str, choice3:typing.Optional[str], choice4:str,choice5:str):
    print(choice1,choice2,choice3,choice4,choice5)
```

Second:

```
@bot.tree.command(name='decide2', description='Bing will now help you to decide what happens')        
@app_commands.describe(choice1 = "What is your 1st choice?")
@app_commands.describe(choice2 = "What is your 2nd choice?")
@app_commands.describe(choice3 = "What is your 3rd choice?")
@app_commands.describe(choice4 = "What is your 4th choice?")
@app_commands.describe(choice5 = "What is your 5th choice?")
async def decide2(interaction: discord.Interaction, choice1: str, choice2: str, choice4:str,choice5:str,choice3:str=None):
    print(choice1,choice2,choice3,choice4,choice5)
```